# How to access va_list inside subsequent block

Tags: syntax, scope, objective-c-blocks, variadic-functions, variadic

The method signature is...

```
- (void)blahBlahBlah:(NSString*)format, ... NS_FORMAT_FUNCTION(1,2) {

   va_list args; va_start(args,format);

   void(^SOME_BLOCK)(void) = ^{ [Heathens prayToJesusWith:
                           [NSString.alloc initWithFormat:kFMT       
                                                arguments:args];  }; ...
   va_end(args);
}
```

However Xcode whines about `args` inside the `SOME_BLOCK`... `Cannot refer to declaration with an array type inside block`.  Why not?  It's "in scope", no?  Tried `__block va_list` to no avail.  Advice? Rationales?

Answer (score 6):

`va_list` is an opaque type that is implementation-dependent and platform-dependent. It could be that on your particular system is is implemented as some kind of array. Blocks cannot capture variables of array type. The C standard imposes certain restrictions on the use of `va_list`, but there is no explicit mention of any issues with blocks.

If you are sure that the block will run within the lifetime of this function (which it must otherwise anyway; because `args` is only meaningful between `va_start` and `va_end`), then one solution is to create another variable that is `va_list *`, set to `&args`, and then capture that and dereference it when you need to use it.

Comment: this was the best solution I could found. All other questions are full with answers without solution. linking this one.